# material-table Make Row Editable on Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

Using the [material-table](https://material-table.com/) library, I am trying to make table rows editable on double click. Clicking the row should have the same effect as clicking the edit button on the leftmost side in the actions column. I have successfully linked into the correct event handler, denoted by the alert box when double clicking a row now.

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-microservice-73iq8?file=/src/App.js:0-1203

```js
import React from "react";
import MaterialTable, { MTableBodyRow } from "material-table";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <MaterialTable
      columns={[
        { title: "Adı", field: "name" },
        { title: "Soyadı", field: "surname" },
        { title: "Doğum Yılı", field: "birthYear", type: "numeric" },
        {
          title: "Doğum Yeri",
          field: "birthCity",
          lookup: { 34: "İstanbul", 63: "Şanlıurfa" }
        }
      ]}
      components={{
        Row: props => (
          <MTableBodyRow
            {...props}
            onDoubleClick={() => {
              alert("Make row editable");
            }}
          />
        )
      }}
      editable={{
        onRowAdd: newData =>
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve();
          }),
        onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve();
          }),
        onRowDelete: oldData =>
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve();
          })
      }}
      data={[
        { name: "Mehmet", surname: "Baran", birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 }
      ]}
      title="Demo Title"
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pure hack, there is no such event that you can trigger,

So I just dig deep into the core `object` to find the event triggers, and I found it inside `props.actions`

`props.actions` contains the array of `actions`, such `add`, `edit`, `delete`, so by taking the ref of it you can trigger any event from it.

Here is the code snippet for it, have a look :

```
<MTableBodyRow
    {...props}
    onDoubleClick={(e) => {
        console.log(props.actions) // <---- HERE : Get all the actions
        props.actions[1]().onClick(e,props.data); // <---- trigger edit event
        alert("Make row editable");
    }}
/>
```

**WORKING DEMO** :

[image: Edit #SO-material-onclick-edit]