# Edit additional fields with material-table that are not in the row

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-table

I have a [material table](https://material-table.com) that shows some of the remote data in row fields. It's impossible, nor wanted, to add all the fields in a single row. I do want to be able to edit some more fields that are not in de row. My thinking was that I could show those additional fields in a detail panel if the user so desires. Obviously the most used data would be in the regular row fields.

My question is: how I can treat the detail panel functionally as an 'extension' of the row, so that I can have the editing/validation capabilities of material table on all the additional fields as well.

Maybe my question is too solution oriented, in that case, how do you deal with editing data that doesn't quite fit on a single material-table row? What approaches could one take that fit well with material design guidelines?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, you could just place a "details" button in the final row, with an modal, redirect or tooltip containing the data.

If i misunderstand you, please post some code so we may better suggest options.

Comment: I would like the 'edit row' functionality of material-table to then also work on whatever fields are shown in the modal, not just the row fields. Is that possible? A detail panel seems appropriate in that case.

Comment: Could you use something like this to open a modal form, and submit new data for your table?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62316709/material-table-make-row-editable-on-click

Comment: Yeah, the alternative approach would be to just show a completely different form/modal to edit all the fields and basically skip the material-table 'edit row' functionality. I was hoping to avoid that because the default edit capabilities are quite powerful and well integrated.

Comment: Perhaps you can keep both, and on edit row submit you open the details form, collect the extra data?